# Практика ОП  на JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Привет.

Прочитал про ОП. Немного разобрался с паттернами. Остался вопрос, где применять и как знания.

Может кто подскажет, где посмотреть применение ООП на практике? (Аналогично, чтобы разбираться в верстке, нужно сначала посмотреть проект, как верстают другие.)

Может у вас с работы остались решения или есть готовые проекты. Если да, дайте посмотреть.

Comment: Сейчас ковыряю Bacbone фреймворк. Там очень хорошо и правльно показано наследование и вообще работа с классами. Без всяких наворотов https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js

Comment: спасибо посмотрю

Comment: [Annotated Source](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html) правда master немного обновился, но всё равно с комментами приятнее изучать, к тому же могу посоветовать [Backbone.js: Hacker’s Guide](http://dailyjs.com/2012/08/16/mvstar-6/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Прямо так брать и применять паттерны - обычно ничем хорошим это не заканчивается. Максимум синглтоном, и то, далеко не в самом красивом его варианте.

Хочется посмотреть? очень легко. Качайте популярные js фреймфорки, например jQuery (который, по некоторым данным используется более чем на половине "популярных сайтов").
Также, можно скачать десятки других cms, например drupal, joomla (и пусть не огорчает то, что они на php/python - к пользователю то все равно приходит html+js).

И третий способ. js можно всегда подсмотреть (иногда его прячут, но разве его спрячешь?). Открывайте сайты популярных сайтов - Google, Yandex, slashdot. Да и Хэшкод не забывайте:) Смотрите им в сорцы и изучайте.

Да, в основном будут попадаться кривые поделки студентов. Но кто мешает попробовать написать их "правильно"? Но иногда, изучая даже самый странный код, можно найти чудесный прием.

Поэтому, хватит печалиться, пора читать чужой код и писать свой.